# Get Billing Address for PayPal Mobile User

Tags: android, mobile, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

For tax and licensing purposes, I need to get some billing information (at least a zip code, although preferably a full address) from users making payments through PayPal's mobile payments library (I am using the Android version.)

Unfortunately, none of this information seems to be returned by the Adaptive Payments API, which seems to only support shipping addresses.  The only work-around that I can see is to request a shipping address and then verify that it is the same as the billing address.

Surely this is a common problem.  Does anyone know how to get billing address info for users through the mobile payments library?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the benefits of PayPal for consumers is that they don't have to share billing information with all the different merchants they're buying product from.  As a protection thing, PayPal doesn't share "billing" information.  The only address they will provide is a shipping address when necessary.

Like you said, though, you could simply make sure the shipping address provided was "confirmed" which means it matches the billing address of a credit card the buyer has on file with PayPal.

True billing addresses only come into play with PayPal when you're using Payments Advanced or Payments Pro and you're working with actual AVS and CVV2 results.

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid that was true.  Time to look for another payment processor.